# Console Application receiving TLS exception "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"while calling service endpoint

Tags: azure, tls1.2

I'm trying to validate a few APIs by calling from my local machine to the API Service Endpoint. I have already configured in the code

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new
RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, 
  sslPolicyErrors) => true;
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {                                                                         
            var status  = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);         
            }
```

When making a GET call, I'm running into the below exception. Any help on this exception is much appreciated.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create an SSL/TLS secure channel.

From the same console application, I could make a successful call to another endpoint. Do I need to ask server to provide me Public Certificate and stored in our Windows 11 machine?

Comment: There are a few sites that require TLS 1.3; perhaps the API you're calling is one of them?